# Navigation bar and logo graphics will not stick together

Tags: html, css

There is a little white gap in between the top of my navigation bar and the bottom of my logo graphics. How can I get these to stick together? Am I missing a selector like *header* or *nav*? Maybe I missed a declaration?

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid #0009bc;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

a:link, a:visited {
  display: block;
  width: 140px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #20dbd4;
  background-color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover, a:active {
  background-color: #20dbd4;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow, noarchive"/>
<title>Grid Design</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="/images/grid-design.jpg" alt="Grid Design" style="width: 987px; height: 243px;"/>
  </header>
  <nav>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">news</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#products">products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#photos">photos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to use an actual image in your example if we're going to see the actual issue, but you could try setting the image to `display:block`

Comment: show the original issue, try to post a fiddle demo and a screenshot

Comment: http://s27.postimg.org/nxvxbowb7/screenshot.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare the image as `display:block` and then centre as required.

The image is `display:inline` by default which means it is affected by `whitespace`...making the image into block element resolves the issue.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vmve6uup/)

**CSS**

```
header img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could set the margin of the nav to -4 so:

**CSS:**

```
nav {
     margin: -4px 0 0 0;
}
```

But this is not the only way...actually this should be your last resort !! There are several better ways to do this.